# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined in ProductList.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This questions already asked, but am not understand because am new in **React Js**.

I try to list all product using `react js`, but it showing following error
[image]

This is my **ProductList.js** code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class ProductList extends Component {
    state = {
        products : []
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.getProducts()
    }

    getProducts = _=>{
        fetch('http://localhost:2020/productList')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => this.setState({products : response.data}))
        .catch(err=>console.error(err))
    }

    renderProduct = (_id, productName) => <div key={_id}>{productName}</div>

    render() {
        const { products } = this.state;

        return (
            <div className="container">
                <h1>Product List</h1>
                <div>
                    { products.map(this.renderProduct) }
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default ProductList
```

Help me to solve this issue.

> Please suggest me Node js + React js + mongoDB tutorials.

Comment: `{ products ? products.map(this.renderProduct) : null }`

Comment: try {products && products.map(this.renderProduct) }

Comment: @ritaj: Now error not come, but values not showing

Comment: try printing your response in getProducts mehod

Comment: @RameshS please check whats is coming in response

Comment: Side note, it should be `products.map((product, index) => {})` Also verify if response.data is an array, looks like response.data is `undefined`

Answer (score 3):

Use this : products  &&  products.map

Answer (score 1):

```
{products && products.map(this.renderProduct)}
```

or try example below if you are using create-react-app

```
{products?.map(this.renderProduct)}
```

also i think you need to change here order

```
renderProduct = (productName, _id) => <div key={_id}>{productName}</div>
```

Comment: what will be the effect of changing order?

Comment: if you are using array of items,first argument will be the item,second one index,so i think you want to display item inside the div and not the index

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HPIjjFGYSJ4 see `18.58`. Here data's are coming but your code not showing

Comment: thats because its using destructure in renderProduct = ( { _id, productName } ) =>

Answer (score 1):

This is how your code should be,

```
return (
    <div className="container">
        <h1>Product List</h1>
         <div>
            {products && products.map((product)=>this.renderProduct(product._id,product.productName)) }
         </div>
     </div>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

since setState is asynchronous it take time therefore products get empty. try with async method

```
class ProductList extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       products : []
    }
    this.getProducts()
  }

getProducts = async () => {
       await fetch('http://localhost:2020/productList')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => this.setState({products : response.data}))
        .catch(err=>console.error(err))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would handle the null data issue in the getProducts function, that way your products is always an empty array if response.data is null.

```
.then(response => this.setState({products : response.data || []})
```